# Address PHP ArrayIndex in SQL Server statement

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to execute a while loop in a SQL Server statement. This statement is placed in PHP and contains several PHP variables. I receive parsing error which does not makes any sense to me. I provide a array which contains strings. Further I point to my array value with a index, the output is a string. *myArray[2] = "bird"*.

Still I receive a parsing error. I declare @CurrentValue as VARCHAR and also SET string content. Of course a better solution would be to perform the loop outside of SQL with PHP instead. Lets just say, I do no thave other possibilites to perform those task, like shown.

Any help or hint is higly appreciated. The error points exactly to my @CurrentValue declaration line.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected string content "", expecting "-" or identifier or variable or number

My code looks like:

```
$myArray = ["cat", "dog", "bird"];
$myArrayLength = count($myArray);

$sql = "...
        DECLARE @PhpArrayIndex INT = 0
        DECLARE @PhpArrayLength INT = '$myArrayLength'

        WHILE @PhpArrayIndex <= @PhpArrayLength
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @CurrentValue VARCHAR(10) = '$myArray[' + @PhpArrayIndex + ']';

            INSERT INTO dbo.myTable (animals)
            VALUE (@CurrentValue)

            SET @PhpArrayIndex += 1;
        END
        ..."
```

Comment: You are mixing PHP variable interpolation with SQL server side variables.
PHP try to expand the content of *$myArray[]* but it doesn't know what @PhpArrayIndex is, while SQL server will not understand what $myArray is.
Perhaps you can declare a SQL variable in the same way of *@PhpArrayLength* that contains *$myArray* values. Otherwise you can do a loop in PHP that executes a query for each cycle.

Comment: I insert a object before my loop. Which creates a unique ID. I store this ID with the help of SQL OUTPUT for further usage, which I need t insert next to @CurrentValue. SCOPE_IDENTITY or IDENTITY would cause errors during mulitple executions and might return a wrong id. As I understand, OUTPUT will be used only in the same statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your @CurrentValue declaration statement in your SQL code is causing trouble because you attempted to merge an integer value and a string, an invalid operation for SQL Server. Instead, try relying on the CONCAT function to bring these two values together.

modified SQL.

```
$myArray = ["cat", "dog", "bird"];
$myArrayLength = count($myArray);

$sql = "...
        DECLARE @PhpArrayIndex INT = 0
        DECLARE @PhpArrayLength INT = '$myArrayLength'

        WHILE @PhpArrayIndex < @PhpArrayLength
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @CurrentValue VARCHAR(10) = CONCAT('$myArray[', @PhpArrayIndex, ']');

            INSERT INTO dbo.myTable (animals)
            VALUES (@CurrentValue)

            SET @PhpArrayIndex += 1;
        END
        ..."
```

I made a tweak to the WHILE condition by swapping <= with <, owing to the PHP array's starting index of 0. Meanwhile, to add @CurrentValue to the table, I utilized the VALUES keyword in lieu of VALUE in the INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary issue is that you are injecting your data directly in to your query. **Never do this,** it is dangerous and can cause injection attacks.

You should use a [**Table Valued Parameter**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/use-table-valued-parameters?view=sql-server-ver16) for this.

First declare a table type in your database, from SSMS

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.StringList (value varchar(10) NOT NULL);
```

Then pass it through

```php
$myArray = [["cat"], ["dog"], ["bird"]];
$params = [
    [["StringList" => $myArray, "dbo"]],
];

$sql = "
INSERT INTO dbo.myTable (animals)
SELECT value
FROM ? AS t;
";
```

Note that `$myArray` is a doubly-nested jagged array.